# Graph can be partitioned into A and B with $|A| \le O(n\log \delta/\delta)$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a graph with $n$ vertices and minimum degree $\delta > 10$. Prove
that there is a partition of $V$ into two disjoint subsets $A$ and $B$ so that $|A| \le O (\frac{n \ln \delta}{\delta})$ , and
each vertex of $B$ has at least one neighbor in $A$ and at least one neighbor in $B$.

Comment: I don't understand what $|A|\leq O(\frac{n\ln\delta}\delta)$ means, as $n$ and $\delta$ are fixed (so I don't understand in what this gives a constraint about the cardinality of $A$.

Comment: I think if $ T \le c n^k $  for some $c >0 $ we can write $T = O(n^k)$ or $T \le O(n^k)$. So it just asks us to prove the existence of some constant $c>0$ such that $|A| \le c \frac{n \ln \delta}{\delta}$.

Comment: This is exercise 4 in section 1.6 in Alon and Spencer's "[The Probabilistic Method](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=XLwRrn4rpk4C)".

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because this is a textbook problem, I try to put my thoughts related to the text.
If we think about related problems, one can realize that $A$ is actually a dominating set:
  for every vertex in $B$, it has some neighbor in $A$.
  However, we require $B$ to have one more property: it contains no isolated vertices after $A$ is removed.
  Observe that, given a dominating set $D$ of $G$,
  if we move all the isolated vertices in $G|_{V-D}$ into $D$,
  then we have a dominating set with desired property satisfied.

This motivates a binomial sampling as follows: with a parameter $p \in (0,1)$,
  for each $v \in V$, $\Pr[v \in A_1] = p$.
  Let $A_2$ be the set of vertices not dominated by $A_1$
  (that is, for each vertex $w \in A_2$, none of its neighbors is in $A_1$).
  As described in the text, $A_1 \cup A_2$ is a dominating set.

Now let $A_3$ be the set of vertices not in $A_1 \cup A_2$,
  but all its neighbors are in $A_1$ or $A_2$. If we move $A_3$ into the dominating set,
  then as discussed above, $A = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3$ satisfies the requirement.
  We compute the expectation of $|A|$, which is ${\bf E}[|A_1|] + {\bf E}[|A_2|] + {\bf E}[|A_3|]$.
  The only difficulty lies in $|A_3|$. Consider $v \in A_3$, and one of its neighbor $w$.
  Then $\Pr[w \in A_1] = p$ and $\Pr[w \in A_2] < (1-p)^{\delta+1}$.
  Thus $\Pr[(w \in A_1) \vee (w \in A_2)] < p + (1-p)^{\delta+1}$.
  Therefore $\Pr[v \in A_3] < (1-p)(p + (1-p)^{1+\delta})^\delta$.

Therefore the expected size of $A$ is
  \begin{align*}
    n \Big( \big( p + (1-p)^{1+\delta} \big) + (1-p)\big( p + (1-p)^{1+\delta}\big)^{\delta} \Big)
  \end{align*}
  If we plug in $p = \ln(1+\delta)/(1+\delta)$, note that $p + (1-p)^{1+\delta} < 1$,
  so this is $O(n\ln\delta/\delta)$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that I think avoids assumptions of independence of neighbors sets (I bound by using an independent set of vertices). I think that otherwise making this assumption causes trouble: consider $K_{\delta, \delta}$. Using the notation of the above answer, for any vertex $v$ in the graph:

\begin{align*}
Pr[v \in A_3] = (1-p)p^{\delta} + (1-p)^{\delta}(1 - p^{\delta} - (1-p)^{\delta})
\end{align*}

which is bigger than $(1-p)(p+(1-p)^{1+\delta})^{\delta}$ for $\delta = 20$ and $p = 0.145 \approx \ln(1+20) / (1 + 20)$ (though the choice of $p$ is unimportant here), against the described bound.

I think if we randomly choose a first set $A_1$ then consider the set $\overline{A_2}$ of vertices not in $A_1$ and not adjacent to $A_1$, we can bound by taking a maximal independent subset $A_2$ of $\overline{A_2}$ and then proceeding as above. I am still a little suspicious of my approach, since I never really used the specific bound $\delta > 10$.

---

Construct a subset $R$ of the vertices $V$ by adding each vertex to $R$ independently with fixed probability $p$ (with $p$ to be determined later). Let $\overline{S}$ be the set of vertices $v$ which are not in $R$ and are not adjacent to any vertices in $R$.

Construct a set $S \subseteq \overline{S}$ as follows. If $\overline{S} = \varnothing$, then let $S = \varnothing$. Otherwise, order the vertices of $\overline{S}$ somehow: $\overline{S} = \{v_{1}, \ldots, v_{k}\}$. Add $v_{1}$ to $S$. For $i = 2, \ldots, k$, if $v_{i}$ is not adjacent to any vertices already in $S$, then add $v_{i}$ to $S$. Otherwise, discard it. (The point of this is to get a maximal independent subset.)

Every vertex $v \in V$ must either be in $R$, be in $S$, or be adjacent to a vertex in $R \cup S$: assume for contradiction that $v \not \in R \cup S$ and $v$ is not adjacent to any vertices in $R \cup S$. Since $v \not \in R$ and $v$ is not adjacent to any vertices in $R$, $v \in \overline{S}$. Since $v \not \in S$, it must have been discarded in the above procedure because it had a neighbor already in $S$, i.e. $v$ is adjacent to a vertex in $R \cup S$, a contradiction.

So $R \cup S$ is a dominating set. Let $T$ be the set of vertices $v \in V \setminus (R \cup S)$ such that all neighbors of $v$ are in $R \cup S$. Choose $A = R \cup S \cup T$ (so $B = V \setminus A$). Since $R \cup S$ is dominating, each vertex $b \in B$ is adjacent to a vertex in $A$. Furthermore, such $b$ must have a neighbor in $B \setminus \{b\}$ since otherwise $b \in T \subseteq A$. This choice of $A$ and $B$ then satisfies the problem.

$R,S,$ and $T$ are disjoint, so $\mathbb{E}[|R \cup S \cup T|]=\mathbb{E}[|R|] + \mathbb{E}[|S|] + \mathbb{E}[|T|]$. For any vertex $v \in V$, $\mathbb{P}[v \in R] = p$ so $\mathbb{E}[|R|] = np$. Since $S \subseteq \overline{S}$, $\mathbb{E}[S] \le \mathbb{E}[\overline{S}]$. $\mathbb{P}[v \in \overline{S}] \le (1-p)^{\delta + 1}$ so $\mathbb{E}[|S|] \le n(1-p)^{\delta + 1}$.

Given a vertex $v \in V$ with $d \ge \delta$ neighbors and non-empty $R' \subset N_G(\{v\})$ (strict subset), consider the event $E_{v, R'}$ that $v \not \in R \cup S$, $R' \subseteq R$, and $N_G(\{v\}) \setminus R' \subseteq S$. If any vertices in $N_G(\{v\}) \setminus R'$ are adjacent, then $Pr[E_{v,R'}] = 0$. Likewise, if any vertices in $R'$ are adjacent to any vertices in $N_G(\{v\}) \setminus R'$, then $Pr[E_{v,R'}] = 0$. This leaves the case when $R'$ and $N_G(\{v\}) \setminus R'$ have no common edges and $N_G(\{v\}) \setminus R'$ is an independent set. The probability that $N_G(\{v\}) \setminus R' \subseteq S$ is at most the probability that $N_G(\{v\}) \setminus R' \subseteq \overline{S}$ so:

\begin{align*}
Pr[E_{v,R'}] \le (1-p)p^{|R'|} (1-p)^{d-|R'|}(1-p)^{\delta-1}
\end{align*}

since $N_G(\{v\}) \setminus R'$ has at least $\delta - 1$ neighbors other than $v$, none of which can be in $R'$. It is clear that this bound then also works in the two "$0$-cases" above. Then:

\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{P}[v \in T] &\le (1-p)\left[p^{d} + \sum_{r=1}^{d-1} \binom{d}{r}p^{d-r}(1-p)^r(1-p)^{\delta-1}\right] \\
    &= (1-p)[p^{d} + (1-p)^{\delta-1}(1 - p^{d} - (1-p)^{d})] \\
    &\le (1-p)[p^{d} + (1-p)^{\delta-1}] \\
    &\le (1-p)p^{\delta} + (1-p)^{\delta}\\
    \Longrightarrow \mathbb{E}[|R|+|S|+|T|] &\le np + n(1-p)^{\delta+1} + n(1-p)p^{\delta} + n(1-p)^{\delta} \\
    &\le 2np + 2n(1-p)^{\delta} \\
    &\le 2np + 2ne^{-p\delta}
\end{align*}

From taking the derivative, $p = \ln \delta / \delta$ is the best choice, giving $\mathbb{E}[|R \cup S \cup T|] \in O(\frac{n \log \delta}{\delta})$, so it exists.